# jquery imgAreaSelect not working in bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, img-area-select-jquery

I am playing with jQuery imgareaselect plugin located here: https://plugins.jquery.com/imgareaselect/

and works like so:

```
$('#img_for_select').imgAreaSelect({
    x1: 10,
    y1: 10,
    x2: 100,
    y2: 100,
    handles: true,
    parent: '#modal_content'
});
```

here's a fiddle for pure imgAreaSelect to demonstrate that it does work
http://jsfiddle.net/kurtgn/vaf5f9mf/

and here's one that triggers a modal window and tries to apply the same imgAreaSelect to the same image (inside the modal).
http://jsfiddle.net/kurtgn/f0x8o2L7/

why doesn't the latter work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use imgAreaSelect right after the modal is opened by using its `shown.bs.modal` event. Like this

```
    var myModal = $('#myModal').modal({
        show: false
    });

    myModal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#img_for_select').imgAreaSelect({
            x1: 10,
            y1: 10,
            x2: 100,
            y2: 100,
            handles: true,
            parent: '.modal-content' 
        });
    });
```

Also, the parent should be `.modal-content` and not `#modal-content`. *(That's not  the issue though)*

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/f0x8o2L7/7/**

PS:

Made the below changes to the button so that the modal window is opened on click

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="modalWindow">Launch demo modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line and it will work:

```
parent: '#modal_content'
```

Your code should now look like :

```
$('#modalWindow').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal();

    $('#img_for_select').imgAreaSelect({
        x1: 10, y1: 10, x2: 100, y2: 100,
        handles: true
    });
})
```

Comment: You should see an area selected on the image after the modal is opened

Comment: @LuthandoLoot, where is the expandable area like in http://jsfiddle.net/kurtgn/vaf5f9mf/